# Oracle update BLOB column with encrypted value set NULL value when blob is more than 3000-4000 char

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, blob

In a Oracle 11g database I have a table with a blob column in which I want to put encrypted datas. 
I have this function in my database :

```
create or replace FUNCTION encryptmyBLOB(content IN BLOB, key in VARCHAR2)
RETURN BLOB  AS
    CRYPTED BLOB;
    encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=
                            SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128
                          + SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                          + SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
BEGIN 
        dbms_lob.createtemporary(CRYPTED,true);
        SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT(
            dst => CRYPTED,
            src => content,
            typ => encryption_type,
            key => SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash (UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (key, 'WE8ISO8859P15'), SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_MD5),
            iv  => utl_raw.cast_to_raw('/myIV'));
        return CRYPTED;
    end if;
END;
```

and my application send query with params like this :

```
UPDATE mytable SET myColumn=encryptmyBLOB(:SERIAL,:ENCRYPT_KEY) WHERE ...
```

This works well when the SERIAL param contain less than approximately 4000 bytes but when SERIAL contain more data I get a database error.

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I suspect that my application Oracle driver send a LONG value in my SERIAL param instead of a BLOB value but I can't confirm it and the UPDATE is correctly done if I bypass my function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Many thanks.

Comment: Which application Oracle driver (for what programming language) are you using?

Comment: And how are you binding the `SERIAL` value?

Comment: Just out of interest, are you using SecureFile LOBs? You could encrypt the whole LOB segment without having to write the code yourself...

Comment: @Thilo I use a devart dbexpress driver for Delphi

Comment: @AlexPoole the binding of the SERIAL value may not be the problem as it works when I bypass encryptmyBLOB function and it also works for mySQL and SQL Server. The param is created with a BLOB type but I put text in it.

Comment: @wolφi I don't know what is SecureFile LOBs. My application can be deployed with MySQL, MSSQL Server or Oracle that's why I decide to encrypt datas in a consistent way between these three DBs. Only the function is DataBase specific.

Comment: Okay, understood. Are you responsible for the table structure?

Comment: yes I can modify the table structure

Comment: Have you tested `encryptmyBLOB` by calling it from PL/SQL? Perhaps the driver you're using is passing the 'BLOB' in your application using the `LONG` data type.

Comment: If you can modify the table structure, than I would recommend to use securefile blobs. You only have to change the create statement. They are faster, better supported, and the old ones are becoming deprecated. Syntax looks like `LOB(mycolumn) STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE mylobtablespace)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: You column is not a `BLOB`-column.

You should change the datatype to `BLOB`, because `LONG`/`LONG RAW` is deprecated:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT613

If you can't change the type of the column, you could check the size of your `BLOB` 'content' within you function:

```
DECLARE
    myBlob   BLOB;
    mySize   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    myBlob := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('1234567890');
    mySize := dbms_lob.getlength(myBlob);

    dbms_output.put_line('Size: ' || mySize); 

    myBlob := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('12345678901234567890');
    mySize := dbms_lob.getlength(myBlob);

    dbms_output.put_line('Size: ' || mySize); 
END;
```

Comment: myColumn is a BLOB column. As I understand the error message "... a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column" it seems to me that it's more the value ("content" parameter of "encryptmyBLOB" or the value return by encryptmyBLOB) that is a LONG value